# Getting text from all the classes on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple elements each with class `p1,p2,p3....p14` So, when I try to get text from the class that was clicked,I get the text from all the classes! For example, when the the text has to be `80` it will be `808080080808080808080`. Is there a work-around for this, else than giving each an `ID`?

```
$('.p1,.p2,.p3,.p4,.p5,.p6,.p7,.p8,.p9,.p10,.p11,.p12,.p13,.p14').click(function(event) {
    if(!playerSelected) {
        playerName = this.title;
        // GETS TEXT FROM ALL CLASSES
        playerNumber = $('.' + this.className + '>strong').text();
        console.log(playerName + " : " + playerNumber);
        playerSelected = true;                   
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please add fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at that target element alone:

```
 playerNumber = $(this).find("strong").text();
```

Now it will get the text from that target element alone.

In your case:

```
playerNumber = $('.' + this.className + '>strong').text();
```

You are actually querying for all elements with matching classname. So it's returning you text from all elements with same classname.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that strong tag in your class element if not just use

```
playerNumber = $(this).text();
```

Try this

```
$('.p1,.p2,.p3,.p4,.p5,.p6,.p7,.p8,.p9,.p10,.p11,.p12,.p13,.p14').click(function(event) {
    if(!playerSelected) {
        playerName = $(this).title;
        // GETS TEXT FROM ALL CLASSES
        playerNumber = $(this).find("strong").text();
        // if strong tag are not in class element
        //playerNumber = $(this).text();
        console.log(playerName + " : " + playerNumber);
        playerSelected = true;                   
    }
});
```

Also you can assign a single call to all in place of using p1, p2....

.pelement

like this

```
$('.pelement').click(function(event) {
    if(!playerSelected) {
        playerName = $(this).title;
        // GETS TEXT FROM ALL CLASSES
        playerNumber = $(this).find("strong").text();
        // if strong tag are not in class element
        //playerNumber = $(this).text();
        console.log(playerName + " : " + playerNumber);
        playerSelected = true;                   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<strong>` tag is inside your class .p1, .p2...etc then you can try this.

```
jQuery('.p1,.p2,.p3,.p4,.p5').click(function (event) {
    alert(jQuery(this).children('strong').text())
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne255o6t/2/)

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, If your `<strong>` element is first level children of where you bind click element. You should use `children()` method as a good practice. `find()` travels to all dome element inside your binding element to find `<strong>` tag.